# Is managing Java EE web app artifacts versions worth it?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven

I have few Maven-based Java web apps which I don't release, only deploy.

I have realized that for a long time, I haven't changed the **versions** of the **produced** artifacts, because it only adds work - changing the versions in all dependent etc.

Even when I work in a team, we don't care much about versions and have 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT all the time, and rather share the code and rebuild all.

My question: What would I use artifacts versions for? Am I missing some nice way of leveraging it?

Update: This question is **not** about justifying Maven and dependencies. It's about **versions of my web app's stuff** .

Comment: I don't think so.  I personally believe that Maven is too complex and restricting to be worth the benefit it provides.  Ant and Ivy are simpler.

Comment: Maven has lots of built in functionality for building web apps. It's actually simpler for beginners to pick up. ANT on the other hand demands that you know how to write the compilation and assembly logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just based on own experience, I decided not to track versions of web app's artifacts. Since it doesn't go public and we are a small team, we only use git tags for versioning, and keep maven artifacts as 1.0-SNAPSHOT all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this question is really about justifying the overhead of using Maven? In that case it's related to the following:

- [Does it still make sense to use Maven when dependent jars are checked in with source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438980/does-it-still-make-sense-to-use-maven-when-dependent-jars-are-checked-in-with-so/11440495)

In my opinion versioning your binaries is just as important as versioning your source:

- If you rely on 3rd party software libraries, they change over time. These libraries in turn have dependencies on others. The world of open source moves rapidly and while it's not fun at least tools like Maven/ivy provide us with tooling to manage this.
- Your released software changes over time. Assuming you've got several developers, ever noticed strange things happening on your deployed environments that you could not reproduce? Without binary versioning how do you roll-back or recreate the problem?
- Assuming the worst, if deployments are happening direct from a developer's PC, how can you be sure he/she has actually committed the changes?

To gain the full power of Maven I'd highly recommend using a Maven repository manager like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) locally. In additon to helping with 3rd party dependencies it's also an ideal place to store your application versions. Even if you continue to generate 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, Nexus will ensure each application build is stored as a unique time-stamped revision within the repository. As time goes on, Nexus can be configured to purge out your old SNAPSHOTS.