# Should I backup maven/ivy dependencies?

Tags: maven, version-control, ivy

In a project with an online dependency management done by ivy/maven, is it good practice to back-up the artifacts e.g. by including them in the projects source code / version control (e.g. svn, git) or is it (safe) enough to so so with pom.xml / ivy.xml? Of course, having the artifacts not backed up somehow makes the project totaly depend on the availability of the maven repo.

EDIT:

The reason for my question is that I fear that certain artifacts are no longer available on the official maven repository, or even that the repository itself is down. In such a case, having the libs under version control gives the security to be able to build the project in such a case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java jar files into a repository (CVS, SVN..)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649015/java-jar-files-into-a-repository-cvs-svn)

Comment: More specifically, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4656359/1743880) answer from the linked duplicate answers this question. Which is "No. Never."

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596494/is-managing-java-ee-web-app-artifacts-versions-worth-it/11599620#11599620

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438980/does-it-still-make-sense-to-use-maven-when-dependent-jars-are-checked-in-with-so/11440495

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is not to backup the artifacts . if the artifact is not available , then you should consider it to change with replacement however I see very rare possibility of this to happen . Any way , you can always get old artifact JAR from your previous build for the scenario when we do't have any option and you have to use old artifact So i will not suggest to keep separate backup  .

thanks ..