# Can I teach Maven to parse ivy.xml and get dependencies from there?

Tags: maven, ivy

Imagine following problem - a project with ivy dependencies which, are resolved through maven repos.

Now I want to have a pom.xml but I don't want to convert all this ivy dependencies (not really matters how exactly - whether it would be by hand or automatically, using something like ivy:makepom).

So, I want basically something like:

```
 <dependencies>
     <some-kind-of-ivy-dependency-resolver/>
 </dependencies>
```

Which will parse ivy.xml get the dependencies and put them to regular maven cache repo.

One who will help me with hint would be a very, very nice man )

Comment: have you looked at the ivy maven plugin? http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Ivy-maven-plugin looks like it can bring in non-maven dependencies

Comment: simplest thing is to use the ivy makepom task, then run Maven.

Comment: @radai, yep, I've tried to but failed.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor, well, the whole point is not to track any changes produces in ivy files in order not to call makepom manually )))

Comment: @shabunc Why do you want to do this? Are you converting your project from ANT to Maven? If so I don't understand why you want to keep the ivy configuration files....

Comment: @MarkO'Connor, I just can not came up and inform everybody that we are moving to maven. The goal is to keep using ivy and maven side-by-side, till everybody will see that maven is indeed a better solution. Though manual migration is inevitable, I want to reduce it as much as possible.

Comment: I just don't get what you're trying to do. Are you planning to move your existing build scripts to Maven but still want to use `ivy.xml`?

Answer (score -1):

My advice would be to recommend Maven for greenfield projects. If projects are already using ivy encourage them as this enables teams to collaborate via your shared Maven repository. My reasoning and logic is outline in the following answer:

- [Does it still make sense to use Maven when dependent jars are checked in with source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438980/does-it-still-make-sense-to-use-maven-when-dependent-jars-are-checked-in-with-so/11440495#11440495)

Comment: I agree with all of your argument provided, but can not see how this answers the question )))

Comment: @shabunc Getting Maven to parse ivy files does not achieve your objective of converting your users (it will also never happen, Maven is too opininated a tool)... I also disagree with your premise that Maven is better than ivy. I have used both extensively and recommend ivy as a better tool for ANT builds.

Comment: you disagree with my premises and don't like the whole idea. I do believe that you most probably are right, which is the most funny part of all this. Nevertheless it is not the answer )))